# How to exclude all files except certain file type/s in VSCODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to exclude all files except certain file type/s in [vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode)?  Since it is not supporting `!` in [glob](/questions/tagged/glob) pattern, I tried following setting but didn't work neither.

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.*": true,
        "**/app.config": false
    }
}
```

> *Also, I saw that there is a feature request in [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/869) but it is a year old issue.  So wondering if StackOverflow community has any update on it.*